# Static website hosted in Azure, HTTPS working HTTP not

Tags: azure, azure-cdn, azure-custom-domain

I have hosted a static website in azure mainly by following the Microsoft tutorials. The process has been to create a storage account, create a CDN endpoint, map my custom domain to the endpoint and then enable HTTPS using an SSL certificate managed by azure.

The custom domain is working but the problem is firstly that although in Azure CDN it says that both HTTP and HTTPS are enabled, I can only access the website via HTTPS and when I try with HTTP the error I get says 'The account being accessed doesn't support HTTP'. The other thing is that in order to navigate to the secure site I have to put the entire URL in the search bar, starting with the https or the website can't be found. I'm not sure if this is normal but if I think of web browsing in general, this isn't usually necessary.

Any ideas on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: check your TLS/SSL settings on the App Service, default is HTTPS only

Comment: Great thanks!! This solved the problem perfectly. Just in case anyone has the same issue you have to select the storage account then on the side menu choose configuration and check the secure transfer required setting.

Comment: I added a proper answer to your question.

Answer (score 5):

Default is that Azure only Allows HTTPS.

> On App Service go to TLS/SSL settings and switch to HTTPS Only to Off.
>
> On Storage Account go to Configuration and change Secure transfer
> required to disabled.

Comment: but this seems to open up http requests. Am I missing something or do we have to open up for http requests in  order to not get that error?