# Azure Static Website: The account being accessed does not support http

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-storage, azure-cdn

I use *Static website* feature of Azure storage account to host React.js application. There is also a CDN endpoint enable for the site (Microsoft Standard CDN pricing tier), so the site URL looks like https://xxx.azureedge.net/. The problem: when I try to access the site via HTTP protocol, it says:

```
The account being accessed does not support http.
HttpStatusCode: 400
ErrorCode: AccountRequiresHttps
RequestId : 46959fc9-a01e-006d-2bc5-6b781e000000
TimeStamp : 2020-08-06T07:48:01.6590412Z
```

I would like the user to be redirected to HTTPS version.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63188260/static-website-hosted-in-azure-https-working-http-not

Answer (score 11):

You can allow HTTP without CDN:
Under "Settings"->"Configuration" set "Secure tranfer required" to "Disabled".

[image: Screenshot Azure Storage Portal - Secure transfer required]

However, for redirecting to HTTPS you need for example CDN.

Comment: For new Azure user, this page is located in the Blob Storage Account. In additional, to configure it via Terraform, it is set by `enable_https_traffic_only ` in `azurerm_storage_account`. :)

Answer (score 7):

The solution was found in Microsoft documentation https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-standard-rules-engine#redirect-users-to-https
It says that the redirection from HTTP to HTTPS can be configured in the Rules engine of CDN endpoint.
It makes sense to keep in mind that:

- the rules will not be applied immediately, in my case it started to work in 10 minutes.
- the Rules engine is available for Standard Microsoft and Premium Verizon.